# How do I make a vue component that accepts any prop?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I know I can write a component that would take a single prop to render an icon as follows

```
<template>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">{{ name }}</span>
</template>
...
```

But I was wondering is it possible to create a VueJS component (doesn't have to be an SFC) that would allow me to say...

```
<Icon navigate_next />
```

rather than

```
<Icon name="navigate_next" />
```

I'd also like to have it with proper typings (hence why I tagged this with Typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it using a SFC with TypeScript based on @moritz's answer

```xml
<template>
  <span
    class="material-symbols-outlined icon"
    :class="classObject"
    :style="style"
    >{{ name }}</span>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { StyleValue, useAttrs } from "vue";

const { classObject, styleAttr, ...attrs } = useAttrs();
const style = styleAttr as StyleValue;
const name = Object.keys(attrs)[0];
</script>
```

This implementation does what I needed plus adds support for `style` and `class` passthroughs.

Here's an improved one using `@mdi/js` to avail of tree-shaking

```xml
<template>
  <svg role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" :width="size" :height="size">
    <title v-if="alt">{{ alt }}</title>
    <path :d="path" />
  </svg>
</template>
<style scoped>
path {
  fill: currentColor;
}
</style>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import Icons from "./icons";
import { useAttrs } from "vue";
const { alt, size, name } = withDefaults(
  defineProps<{ alt?: string; size?: string | number; name?: string }>(),
  {
    size: 24,
  }
);
const attrs = useAttrs();
const iconName = name ?? Object.keys(attrs)[0];
const path = Icons[iconName] ?? Icons.mdiHelpBoxOutline;
</script>
```

It needs a separate import to pick specific icons

```
// https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/
// don't load the whole thing just add the ones that we require over time.
import {
  mdiChevronRight,
  mdiFacebook,
  mdiHelpBoxOutline,
  mdiInstagram,
  mdiLinkedin,
  mdiTwitter,
} from "@mdi/js";
// In order to pass Typechecks, the imports need to be copied here.
export default {
  mdiChevronRight,
  mdiFacebook,
  mdiHelpBoxOutline,
  mdiInstagram,
  mdiLinkedin,
  mdiTwitter,
} as Record<string, string>;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think props have to have a fixed name, so that vue can bind it. If you use an attribute that is not bound by props, it will land in `attrs`, and you can access it from there.

However, if there are multiple attributes, the hard part is figuring out, which one describes the icon.

Another possibility is to use a slot, i.e.

```
<Icon>navigate_next</Icon>
```

Here is a simple example:

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const IconFromAttrs = {
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
    return () => [           
      h('span', {class: 'mdi mdi-36px mdi-' + Object.keys(attrs)[0]} ),
    ]
  }
}

const IconFromSlot = {
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
    return () => [           
      h('span', {class: 'mdi mdi-36px mdi-' + slots.default()[0].children}),
    ]
  }
}


const App = { 
  components: { IconFromSlot, IconFromAttrs },
  data() {
    return {
    }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.4.55/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<div id="app">

  <div>
    From attrs:
    <icon-from-attrs pig/>
  </div>

  <div>
    From slot:
    <icon-from-slot>dog</icon-from-slot>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Neither slots nor attrs can be automatically typed, so you will have to provide types explicitly with `as string`.

Vuetify's `v-icon` uses the approach with slots. Feels wrong to post their code here, but you can look at it [in GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f00e0017f0779faba82e739178a92078fd986967/packages/vuetify/src/components/VIcon/VIcon.tsx#L35-L44), it's the `slotIcon` starting at line 35. This should give you an idea what checks are needed.

Comment: The one thing I am missing on your answer is the typings.

Comment: Oh, you have to use `as string` in both cases, no way around it. Added it to the answer and a link to Vuetify's `v-icon` code, which uses the slot approach.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can pass the properties of an object without using any attribute in the component. Here is the [`documentation`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object).

You can use `v-bind` without an argument.

```
<Icon v-bind="navigate_next" />
```

In Script **:**

```
navigate_next: {
  name: 'xyz'
}
```

Will be equivalent to **:**

```
<Icon :name="navigate_next.name" />
```